# turtlebot_gazebo demo questions

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a few questions regarding the turtlebot_gazebo demo.

1  > Does the physics simulator gazebo limit the frame rate at 25 fps?

2  > What happens when a node publishes messages to a topic faster than they are being
consumed? Do the messages wait in a queue to be consumed?

3  > And is it possible to have a computation graph where nodes are written using
different client libraries?

4  > Could you also please tell what is the meaning of the term RMS Error in gazebo?

5  > How can a node consume and produce messages to the same topic? Is it some kind of closed feedback loop control for that particular node?

Thanks and regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28208/turtlebot_gazebo-demo-questions/) by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-02-22**:
Shouldn't this be five questions?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-02-22**:
I agree! At least put the common topic of all questions in the title, e.g. "turtlebot_gazebo demo details".

**Comment by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on 2012-02-23**:
@Marcus Thanks for pointing that out. Title changed )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. The "frame rate" of Gazebo (the rate at which it's drawn to screen) is based on your computer's hardware. Gazebo runs two threads, a physics thread and a render thread. The physics thread's update rate can be set in the `.world` file.
2. ROS queues all incoming messages until nodes are able to service those callbacks. This queue length is specified in the constructor of a subscriber.
3. If by "different client libraries" you mean, "can you use C++ and Python for different nodes in the same graph?", then the answer is yes. You may be some nodes in C++ and some in Python with no problem at all.
4. I will omit this for someone more with more Gazebo knowledge.
5. It is not recommended to have a node subscribe to and publish to the same topic. You should have two different topics for this. Since you cannot know which node publishes a certain message on a topic, you could cause a lot of confusion doing this.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

4. RMS error displayed in gazebo (electric) is the root-mean-squared value of the change in Lagrange multipliers (Δλ) as described [here](http://ros.org/wiki/physics_ode/ODE).  It's an approximate indicator of how much the constraint satisfaction step has converged under the quickstep algorithm.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on 2012-02-23**:
Im sorry but that just flew over my head. In any case, is this something that I have to be consciously  aware while using ROS and gazebo?